# BQ: How to check query cost every time

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to show alert or message popup every time I run queries in BQ GUI?I am afraid of spending query cost too much.

I hope BQMate has this function.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at the stackdriver and setup alert policy. May be, you can set up an upper limit and by the time, it reaches this limit, it would alert you with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cost of the query can only be determined when the query is finished, e.g, federated tables, and the newly released clustering tables. If you're concerned about the cost, the best option is to set the [Maximum Bytes Billed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#limit_query_costs_by_restricting_the_number_of_bytes_billed) option, then you can be sure you'll never be charged for more than that. You can set a default value for this option in your project, but right now you have to contact the support to set it for your project.

Answer (score -1):

A fast way to get a query cost estimation is checking the amount of data processed on the right side of the screen in the `query validator`, by performing a [dry-run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#price_your_queries_before_running_them). Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-web-ui#query_a_public_dataset) a "query validator" example. You have two options to calculate the cost:

1. Manually: query pricing is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) on GB units, so you can sum and multiply: `1 free TB per month, $5 per extra TB`. If you expect to query more than 1TB of data per month, you should sum queries' used data to know when to start calculating costs.
2. Automatically: using the online [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#using_the_pricing_calculator), which is available for all Google Cloud Platform products.

If you want to set **custom cost controls**, have a look on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas), since custom quotas are not enabled by default. Cost controls can be applied on **project -level** or **user-level** by restricting the number of bytes billed. Nowadays you have to submit a request from the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.23991922.-917327482.1531466970) to ask for them to be set, on 10TB increments. If the usage exceeds a set quota the error message is quite clear, and is different depending on the project/user quota exceeded. For project quota:

```
Custom quota exceeded: Your usage exceeded the custom quota for
QueryUsagePerDay, which is set by your administrator. For more information,
see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls
```

With no remaining quota, BigQuery stops working for everyone in that project.

If you want to **constantly monitorize billing** data for BigQuery, have a look on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08), which explains how to create a billing dashboard using Data Studio.

I don't know about BQMate since this is from Vaint Inc.